# Using keys() on django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is a quick question with the use of dict.keys()

I'm returning a dictionary in py file
Ex:

```
response['dict'] = {'a': [1,2,4], 'b': [5,6,7]}
```

And in the html i'm try to loop over using keys

```
{% if dict %}
  {% for list in dict.keys() %}
    list
  {% endfor %}
{endif}
```

This is throwing an error.

> TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: 'keys()' from
>   'dict.keys()

Need help here. How to use this in Django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{% if dict %}
  {% for key, value in dict.items %}
    list
  {% endfor %}
{endif}
```

**edit:**

`{% if dict %}` is not needed - if given context's variable is empty (or if it's empty dict), it silently passes:

```
  {% for key, value in dict.items %}
    list
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, the main point here - as clearly explained in the documentation - is that you don't use the calling `()` in Django templates.

Comment: And on a related note. how to use join in django
`{% for key, value in dict.items %}
    ('\n').join(list) ????
{% endfor %}`

Comment: @RaviTeja see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#join

Answer (score -3):

It is probably because `dict` is a reserved keyword in Python. Try

```
{% if d %}
  {% for key in d.keys() %}
    list
  {% endfor %}
{endif}
```

or simply

```
{% if d %}
  {% for key in d %}
    list
  {% endfor %}
{endif}
```

an iterator over a dictionary in python is by default over the keys so you don't have to specify that you want the keys and not `.items()` or `.values()`.

Comment: using `d.keys()` is incorrect - brackets cannot be used in template, correct notation is `d.keys`

Comment: `dict` isn't a reserved keyword it's the name of a builtin type. Python doesn't actually stop you reassigning the name `dict` if you really want to, though admittedly it's not a good idea as you the lose access to the builtin.

Comment: dict was a good catch, but i just used it over here for example. Sorry for the confusion.  yedpodtrzitko's answer solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: @redrah I don't see how that makes it any less reserved. The fact that Python doesn't stop you from overwriting it makes it no less reserved as the name that points to the built in dictionary.

Comment: @MattiLyra I get where you're coming from but my point is that there is an important distinction between a keyword and a name.  For example `class`, `if` etc. are keywords in Python, and therefore it's impossible to give a variable the name `class` as it is reserved for syntax, if you try you'll get a SyntaxError.  A name has no syntactic importance beyond being a name, and so any name can be assigned to any object, even `dict`.